# SQL query with minus and joins

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have three column names, all in one table. Which returns 96 rows. Im trying to use a Minus statement and Join statement to see if there are any duplicates in the database/other tables. The 3 columns are in 3 seperate tables so i am trying to use a Minus and Join statement to get a number of rows that are duplicates. Can anyone help? First time user.

Comment: Can you post your current code so we can help?

Comment: Tip: Take a look at the help center on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, SQL Server does not support MINUS.
Use EXCEPT instead.

Comment: How would I join the tables after adding in except? im trying to subtract from the 96 rows, and get the number of duplicates. Any chance you can do it without a where clause?

Comment: Can you provide more details? From your question is not quite clear what is your specific problem.